# Objective C Showing Recent Issues Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, firebase

i am integrating google analytics for ADMobds using cocoa pods. its integrating successfully.  next i am integrating Firebase SDK for crashlytics using cocoa pods. but i cant able to integrate my project. i got some error. the error is.

Showing Recent Issues
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRApp

so i am trying to integrate manually. but still same issue. in cocoa pods i am integrating this things.

pod 'mopub-ios-sdk'

pod 'GoogleAnalytics'

pod "UITextField_AutoSuggestion"

pod 'ACFloatingTextfield-Objc'

pod 'Firebase/Auth'

pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

pod 'Firebase'

pod 'Firebase/Core'

Comment: Are you sure your Podfile you've posted here is correct?  If it is, you haven't got Crashlytics in it, which seems like it might be a problem.  (See step 1 here https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#add-sdk)

Comment: @Yvihs can you create a chat room please. i have many doubts.

Comment: @Yvihs hi bro i got this issue. Module 'FirebaseCrashlytics' not found